# input type text preview image

Tags: javascript, textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#imghome').change(function () {
$('#imgurlhead').hide();
$('#uimgurl').attr('src', $('#imghome').val())
})
})
</script>
```

[image: before insert image - show]
before insert

```
<div class="advancedoptions">
<fieldset><legend></legend><input type="text" name="imghome" id="imghome" value=""/><input type="button" value="Localizar no Servidor" onclick="BrowseServer();" /><div class="preview-image"><img id="uimgurl" /></div></fieldset> 
</div>
```

[image: after inser - when edit - image preview not show]
after insert - edit

```
<div class="advancedoptions">
<fieldset><legend></legend><input type="text" name="imghome" id="imghome" value="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR"/><input type="button" value="Localizar no Servidor" onclick="BrowseServer();" /><div class="preview-image"><img id="uimgurl" /></div></fieldset> 
</div>
```

question: I need a value in script on edit, when not show image. 
Any help?
thank you!

this is a code of my system.

```
if($thisType == "String"){
  $buffer .= '<legend>'.$thisDesc.
  '</legend><input type="text" name="'.$thisField.
  '" id="'.$thisField.'" value="'.$thisValue.
  '"/><input type="button" value="Localizar no Servidor" onclick="BrowseServer();" /><div class="preview-image"><img id="uimgurl" /></div>';
}
```

Comment: sorry about this.

Comment: Anyway, your question is REALLY hard to understand. Do you need help with PHP or Script or BOTH?

Comment: the script works, however when I add an image url in the text field, and it has the value = "", the image no longer appears. I think it would be in both.

Comment: http://techblu.com/test-previewimage.php